# Bytecode enhancement for fields in a class

Tags: java, properties, bytecode-manipulation

Is it possible to add "hooks" to a class via bytecode enhancement that execute code whenever a class field is read or written?  For example, I'd like to automatically set a "dirty" flag whenever a new value is assigned to a field.

If so, which libraries are best suited to implement this functionality?

Comment: Isn't the purpose of getters and setters to encapsulate functionality such as this?

Comment: Yes, but I want to avoid the hand-coding of functionality that will need to be repeated for each field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to generate getters and setters using the ASM framework. That should get you started.

- http://asm.ow2.org/doc/faq.html#Q9

You can even let your bytecode-rewriter hook into the class-loader and do the rewriting on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to read about AspectJ. Probably this is the tool you are looking for.